# Qt open second window

Tags: c++, qt

I can't open a new window/dialog form mainwindow in qt project.

Open function:

```
    void MainWindow::on_btDodajProdukt_clicked()
{
    newDialog = new DodajProdukt(this);
    newDialog->show();

}
```

MainWindow includes:

```
#include "dodajprodukt.h"
```

MainWindow.h

```
    DodajProdukt *newDialog;
```

Class DodajProdukt is new Window added in desinger.

I get this error:

> mainwindow.obj:-1: błąd:LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall DodajProdukt::DodajProdukt(class QWidget *)" (??0DodajProdukt@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall MainWindow::on_btDodajProdukt_clicked(void)" (?on_btDodajProdukt_clicked@MainWindow@@AAEXXZ)

EDIT:

dodajprodukt.cpp

```
    #include "dodajprodukt.h"
#include "ui_dodajprodukt.h"


DodajProdukt::DodajProdukt(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::DodajProdukt)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

DodajProdukt::~DodajProdukt()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Pro File:

```
    QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Hurtownia
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    dodajprodukt.cpp \
    listaproduktow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    dodajprodukt.h \
    listaproduktow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    dodajprodukt.ui \
    listaproduktow.ui
```

Comment: My guess is that the designer should also generate a `dodajprodukt.cpp` file with the window's implementation that you're not linking with your project.

Comment: @kos how to link it into my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error. Create a new Project and copy the code.
Then create a simple sample code to check if this method works.

Comment: Better yet, don't use the `IDE` at all, if it has bugs and go to the good ole' command line.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on project and then: Clean, Run qmake and Rebuild fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

You must add all files related to DodajProdukt to your .pro file (if using qmake):

For the .ui file created in designer:

```
FORMS += dodajprodukt.ui # assuming that's how it's called
```

And as you apparently have also .h/.cpp files for it:

```
HEADERS += dodajprodukt.h
SOURCES += dodajprodukt.cpp
```

Comment: Have you implemented DodajProdukt::DodajProdukt( QWidget* ) in your .cpp?

Comment: Can you add your .pro file?

Comment: That looks correct and complete. Are you using visual studio? Make sure the .pro changes are picked up and dodajprodukt.cpp is actually compiled. If in doubt, try with clean build.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

and I fix it after deleting .pro.user file and deleting project build folder